# UIScrollView setZoomScale not working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am struggeling with my UIScrollview to get it to zoom-in the underlying UIImageView. In my view controller I set

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
 return myImageView;
}
```

In the viewDidLoad method I try to set the zoomScale to 2 as follows (note the UIImageView and Image is set in Interface Builder):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myImageView.frame.size.width, myImageView.frame.size.height);
 myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(941.0, 990.0);
 myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1;
 myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;
 myScrollView.zoomScale = 0.7;
 myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 myScrollView.delegate = self;

 NSLog(@"zoomScale: %.1f, minZoolScale: %.3f", myScrollView.zoomScale, myScrollView.minimumZoomScale);
}
```

I tried a few variations of this, but the NSLog always shows a zoomScale of 1.0.

Any ideas where I screw this one up?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally got this to work. what caused the problem was the delegate call being at the end. I now moved it up and .... here we go.

New code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];

 myScrollView.delegate = self;
 myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myImageView.frame.size.width, myImageView.frame.size.height);
 myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(941.0, 990.0);
 myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.1;
 myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;
 myScrollView.zoomScale = 0.7;
 myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is caused by the OS calling -viewForZoomingInScrollView. If your delegate is nil, this call doesn't get made, so the view things zooming is disabled.

Comment: Many thanks!! It is really true. But why this happen? This can be not the business of delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example I made. This one is using an image that is included in the resource folder. Compared to the one you have this one adds the UIImageView to the view as a subview and then changes the zoom to the whole view.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"random.jpg"];

imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[self.view addSubview:imageView];

[(UIScrollView *) self.view setContentSize:[image size]];

[(UIScrollView *) self.view setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];

[(UIScrollView *) self.view setMinimumZoomScale:0.5];

}
```

Comment: Can't think why that could cause any trouble, but in my despair tried it anyway. Outcome unchanged

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite late as answers go, but the problem is that your code calls zoomScale before it sets the delegate.  You are right the other things in there don't require the delegate, but zoomScale does because it has to be able to call back when the zoom is complete.  At least that's how I think it works.

Comment: Welcome to SO @turboc!  This comment is undoubtedly helpful, but for future reference, add commentary such as this in the "comments" section below the appropriate post (in this case, the post that has already been accepted as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

My code must be completely crazy because the scale that I use is completely opposite to what tutorials and others are doing. For me, `minScale = 1` which indicates that the image is fully zoomed out and fits the `UIImageView` that contains it.

Here's my code:

```
    [self.imageView setImage:image];
    // Makes the content size the same size as the imageView size.
    // Since the image size and the scroll view size should be the same, the scroll view shouldn't scroll, only bounce.
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.imageView.frame.size;

    // despite what tutorials say, the scale actually goes from one (image sized to fit screen) to max (image at actual resolution)
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat minScale = 1;
    // max is calculated by finding the max ratio factor of the image size to the scroll view size (which will change based on the device)
    CGFloat scaleWidth = image.size.width / scrollViewFrame.size.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = image.size.height / scrollViewFrame.size.height;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = MAX(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
    // ensure we are zoomed out fully
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;
```

This works as I expect. When I load the image into the `UIImageView`, it is fully zoomed out. I can then zoom in and then I can pan the image.